# What are indexes needed to query rows where one attribute is greater than another?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have table

```
create table resources (
    id bigint primary key,
    value nvarchar(255),
    updateId bigint,
    pushUpdateId bigint
);
```

with many rows.
What indexes do I need to create to speedup queries:

```
select id from resources where updateId > pushUpdateId;
```

Comment: No indexes are needed when you are comparing values from the same table..it will always be index scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, no index will help because you have two columns within the same row (well, there are index types but they would not be trivial to implement in SQL Server).  If you do not have many records matching the condition, you can create a computed column and index:

```
create table resources (
    id bigint primary key,
    value nvarchar(255),
    updateId bigint,
    pushUpdateId bigint,
    compare_updateId_pushUpdateId as (case when updateId > pushUpdateId then 1 else 0 end)
);
```

Then, you can create an index:

```
create index idx_resources_2 on resources(compare_updateId_pushUpdateId, id);
```

And then phrase the query as:

```
select id
from resources
where compare_updateId_pushUpdateId = 1;
```